# WP plugin: Why do I need to require the dependencies of a library?

Tags: php, wordpress, path, require

In a WordPress plugin, this does NOT work

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name:       test
 * Plugin URI:        _
 * Description:       _
 * Version:           0.0.1
 * Author:            _
 * Author URI:        _
 * License:           GPL-2.0+
 * License URI:       _
 * Text Domain:       _
 */


// If this file is called directly, abort.
if (!defined('WPINC')) {
    die;
}

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';
```

But this DOES work

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php';
```

Where inside `class-wp-filesystem-direct` you can see that it extends from `class-wp-filesystem-base`

Why do I need to require the two libraries?

---

The error was

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Filesystem_Base' not found in /home/..../domains/..../public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php:16
```

Comment: Hi, for these type of errors I usually try to echo the paths with php and check on the hosting foums, sometimes the paths are wrong, sometimes it is just a capital letter!!, sometimes it some chown root:root or admin:admin or chmod security. yeah it is really difficult to pinpoint the culprit when using shared hosting.

Comment: I've checked the paths, the fact that a core plugin is also failing also discards any typo from my side ... and permissions are 755 in folders and 644 in files (such as `class-wp-filesystem-direct.php` and `class-wp-filesystem-base.php` which now I'm seeing by ftp) ... also I see my user is the owner of everything ... honestly, I've run out of ideas :-|

Comment: Woah sounds like u checked everything man, maybe u can try changing the PHP version if it is a CPanel, don't know but sometimes it can help.

Comment: changed and no changes ...

Comment: Honestly at this point I can only see you duplicating files and copying the files that you require in the same folder of the files that uses require instruction. require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php'; becomes  require_once 'class-wp-filesystem-direct.php'; and you copy the file in the same folder.

Comment: That is a really ugly solution , might lead to a mess but maybe worth a try

Comment: Yes, but still I cannot use WP_Filesystem_Direct::rmdir because it cannot require other classes and crashes | I will see if this happens in local (don't think so) and maybe I try some migration to other hostings ... dunno ... but thanks a lot for commenting!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help man, Best of luck. Just out of curiosity what's your shared hosting provider?

Comment: Hostinger, I've tried different php versions, a manual reinstall of WP, but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The require statement works exactly as it's supposed to, the problem is what you're loading in.  It has dependencies that are unmet, and depends on other things that aren't loaded.

Loading `class-wp-filesystem-direct.php` will load the things in that file, but it won't go searching for other things it needs. WordPress doesn't use PHP autoloading

So some notes:

- WP Admin include files in WordPress don't contain all their dependencies
- If you try to load a class that inherits from a class that hasn't been loaded, you'll get a fatal error
- You shouldn't be trying to include WP Admin files at the top of your plugin, it can cause issues by loading on the frontend
- If you want to work with WP_FileSystem you don't need to load those files and folders

Your problem is that you can't just include random files in WP Admin, they have dependencies that need to be included beforehand.

So your require statement works fine,

Comment: Excellent, do you have any doc to read about it? Didn't know of this behavior. About your 4rth point, if I want to remove a folder, is there any alterantive to rmdir?

Comment: It's basic PHP so I'd suggest php.net,  As for removing a folder you should ask about that on the WP stack, but, I'd  strongly advise against modifying the filesystem from the frontend for performance and security reasons

Comment: Also, it's clear from the questions here and on WPSE that you're trying to do something strange, encountering issues, and asking about solutions, but hiding what you're trying to build, there's much easier simpler ways to do things, but it's very difficult to point you in those directions without knowing the context

Comment: As you pointed out, this question was a basic PHP question indeed. Now if another user sees a problem like this, he won't be interested at all about my secret plans. Let's open a new question for this.